# Applying some analysis to Amaj Cmaj Dmaj Amaj

Tags: chords, chord-theory, chord-progressions

Why does Amaj Cmaj Dmaj Amaj work so well?

How can we describe the relationships between these chords?

What key am I even in? Amaj and Dmaj could be I and IV in A major, or Cmaj and Dmaj could be IV and V in G major? Feels like the former, but how do we explain the Cmaj in An A major key, borrowed parallel?

Is this modal or something?

Any suggestions as to where/how you could develop this progression further?

Answer (score 2):

You could well be in A major.  Does A major feel like home?  ♭III is a frequent visitor to a major key.

Try adding another common interloper, ♭VII.   So you'll have Amaj Cmaj Dmaj Gmaj Amaj. Nice?

Non-diatonic chords don't necessarily change the basic tonality.  And chord progressions don't HAVE to fit a 'circle of 5ths'.

Comment: Interesting. I think I've accidentally done the ♭VII thing before. Another question if I may, when visiting the ♭III or ♭VII what would the melody/lead voice do harmonically? Modulation in to the host chords key seems like the obvious choice, any other thoughts?

Comment: It might centre on the note(s) that are common to both the home key and the 'outside' chord.

Answer (score 1):

A C major in the middle of an A major context can work as a "modal interchange" or "borrowing" or temporary key change to parallel minor Am or something. It's a common thing in jazz and blues, flirting with and alternating between parallel major and minor tonalities.